# Is there any option to extend the time of searching in a mat-select

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have this mat-select that works just as any other dropdown select, but when using the application the user clicks on the dropdown (it is long list) and types from the keyboard e.g. 'goo'. Now, if the user types the e.g. 'goo' letters really fast it works and the option 'Google' is in focus, but if the typing is a bit slower instead of selecting 'Google', 'Oracle' is selected since the last letter typed was 'o' in the example.

Is there any option to extend the timing so when the user goes to the dropdown and types a little slower can still go to the right option?

Hope it is clear, tried my best to explain it with a concrete example. :)

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Company Name" [compareWith]="compareFunc" [(value)]="data">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let c of companies" [value]="c">{{c.CompanyName}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: You only provided HTML, not much can tell from it. Please provide related Js code, as well as `input` where user writes search query

Comment: how long is a "long list"? if we're talking in the thousands or tens of thousands, you probably want to consider filtering this asynchronously from a back end rather than doing it on your client.  If we're talking 100s, then you're probably ok. but if you're seeing latency in the client search, you might be in a situation for a backend filter anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a typeaheadDebounceInterval to `<mat-select>`

EDIT: This is only available since 8.*

https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

example to wait one second:

```
<mat-select [typeaheadDebounceInterval]="1000" placeholder="Company Name" [compareWith]="compareFunc" [(value)]="data">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let c of companies" [value]="c">{{c.CompanyName}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to achieve, but unfortunately is not available in angular 7.x.